# Gauge how much time a query actually takes

Tags: postgresql

A table has an uuid column. I have two options to generate a uuid value to be inserted into it.

1. pre-generate it at API before submitting to DB for `INSERT`
2. have PostgreSql generate

Theoretically option 1 yields better performance, but after the following  simple test in pgAdmin 4 result is not convincing:

```
create table public.testuid (uid uuid)
insert into public.testuid values('e6aec935-824d-47e7-835f-eccb0a4c8485')   -- in ms: 125, 72, 125, 110
insert into public.testuid values(public.gen_random_uuid()) -- in ms: 130, 80, 112, 101
```

**Update**, thanks to @Bergi, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` seems more accurate, and below are the fastest time comparison, pre-gen narrowly outperforms by **0.003ms** (Planning+Execution), may not be benefiting from outside pre-gen.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name To me, those numbers look like they include the connection overhead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's in pgAdmin 4.

Comment: @Bergi Is any way to get report on actual `insert` only? Thanks

Comment: @Jeb50 I think [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) does that, the only caveat is that it doesn't return actual results any more (which doesn't matter for `INSERT` though)

Comment: @Bergi Please see update above, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bergi, instead of relying on pgAdmin's *Message* tab:

> Total query runtime: xxx msec.

Simply prefix whatever your query/statement with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, for example:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
insert into public.testuid values(public.gen_random_uuid());

EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
select * from ...
```

*Data Output* tells the details and `planning time` and `execution time`.